# create excel in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on an ASP.NET web projec using VS2010,C#, I want my users to get excel file output from table reports, I know how to create CSV files but I'm going to create EXCEL files, for example a button that when clicked, enables user to download table data in EXCEL format, also I'm going to write some unicode text (persian, farsi language) into my excel, what are my options? currently I use following code to generate CSV file:

```
            Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "db" + ".csv");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/text";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Clear();

        //append new line
        sb.Append("\r\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < tblDatabase.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //add separator
            for (int j = 0; j < tblDatabase.Rows[0].Cells.Count; j++)
                sb.Append(Table3.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text + ",");
            //append new line
            sb.Append("\r\n");
        }
        Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no big change when modifying this code to create Excel file instead of csv.

Just change your extension

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "db" + ".xls");
```

Change content type

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
```

Here is how to write rows of data in Excel sheet.

```
Response.Write("<table border='1px' bordercolor='black'>");
Response.Write("<tr>");
// loop through column names to display a header row
foreach (DataColumn dc in tblDatabase.Columns)
{
    Response.Write("<td><strong>" + dc.ColumnName + "</strong></td>");
}
Response.Write("</tr>");

int i;
foreach (DataRow dr in tblDatabase.Rows)
{
    Response.Write("<tr>");
    for (i = 0; i < tblDatabase.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        Response.Write("<td>" + dr[i].ToString() + "</td>");
    }
    Response.Write("</tr>");
}
// end table
Response.Write("</table>");
```

Comment: thanks raja, your answer was really simple and effective! my file format is XLS, is it used for office 2003? when I tried to open it using office 2007, it asked me a question regarding format, should I change its extension name to XLSX?

Answer (score 0):

I have had good results using NPOI, learning curve not too steep
  http://npoi.codeplex.com/

Creates native excel files, rather than forcing excel to parse html tables.
The html tables option is ok for some jobs (quicker and easier), but if you have a requirement to make the "real" thing, then try out NPOI.